# How to read phone state over bluetooth

Tags: android-bluetooth, headset, phone-state-listener, obex, hfp

I try to develop an application that connect to mobile phone and read its phone state (incoming call, outgoing call etc.) like a smart watch. I used a smartwatch and connect to my phone, then open android studio to look at logcat. I understand the watch using bluetooth Obex service,Hfp,a2dp Rfcomm services but I didn't find any example or instructions for using them. 
how can i do? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To know the states kindly use the BluetoothHeadsetClient class. This class contains the necessary function to know the phone state (incoming call, outgoing call etc.)